# How to search for a file that is compressed on a external drive from my mac?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, compression

My hard drive was from my Mac. I replaced it with a new hard drive. I was able to dump all the data from the damaged drive onto an external drive. The dump separated some of the files into Word docs, PDFs etc… However the file I’m looking for is an `.odt` file; I do not know the name of the file.

The dump has different versions files called FAT32 1, FAT32 2 and FAT32 3. And a lot of ZIPped files with a naming convention like FILE001 etc... Is there a way I can search the external drive by the extension type?

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that some of the files are dumped to names like FILE001 as zip files. If the `.odt` file you are looking for are zipped up, then you will need to use the second command provided below. Assuming the best case, the `.odt` file is dumped as is and is available as a `.odt` file, then you can use the first command in `Terminal.app` to display them.

```
find /path/to/root/of/dump -type f -and -iname '*.odt'
```

To search the zip files instead, use the following.

```
find /path/to/root/of/dump -iname '*.zip' | while read fname; do unzip -l "$fname"; done | grep "Archive\|.*\.odt"
```

This will output the location of the zip with the files that has extension `.odt` underneath it. If there are no files underneath it, that means that zip does not have files with extension `.odt`.

Example Output as follows.

```
Archive:  ./EDU/test.zip
    5  08-25-2015 12:25   test.odt
Archive:  ./abcd.zip
Archive:  ./okay.zip
    5  08-25-2015 12:25   quiz.odt
```

Here, relative to where I executed the command, I have found three zip files. The three files are, including path, `./EDU/test.zip`, `./abcd.zip`, and `./okay.zip`. Of those three zip files, `test.zip` and `okay.zip` have `.odt` files. On the other hand, `abcd.zip` does not have `.odt` files.

Comment: Thanks...I tried the first command. It executed. But nothing was returned. The second command responds with End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.

Comment: Since the first command returns nothing, it means your `.odt` files are indeed part of the `.zip` files. For the return of the second command, it seems your `.zip` files are not in the format understandable by the `zip` and `unzip` commands. Are you able to test the `.zip` files by unzipping one manually?

Comment: Thanks, some of the Zip files will open. They show up on my downloads and look fine. Others however have a dialog pop up that says "unable to expand .. file doesn't exist". But I can see  the file size of the zip files. And there is something in them..

Comment: What do you mean by showing up in your downloads? Anyway, since some of the files will open up, it means the second command should at least show you the location of some of the `.zip` files. Was the return of the second command only the error message you posted? Or was there other stuff above that? One way to be sure is to use the command : `find /path/to/root/of/dump -type f -and -name '*.zip' | while read fname; do unzip -l "$fname"; done | grep "Archive\|.*\.odt" > t.txt`. This will create file named `t.txt` in location where you executed the command. You can then read that file to check.

Comment: Thanks, It unzips to my download folder..thats all. Anyway here is the total output----->

Comment: End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  /Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive//FAT32 1/0/Download/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive//FAT32 1/0/Download/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip or

Comment: /Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive//FAT32 1/0/Download/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip.zip, and cannot find /Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive//FAT32 1/0/Download/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip.ZIP, period.

Comment: The t.txt file was created..

Comment: Archive:  /Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive//FAT32 1/0/Download/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip

Comment: Can you try `find /path/to/root/of/dump -type f -and -name '*.zip'`? This command finds all the `.zip` files. See just how many zip files it finds. For some reason, the second command only found 1 `.zip` file for you (it should find all the `.zip` files under the path you provide).

Comment: Ok. That's strange it's returning only one zip file

Comment: /Volumes/Seagate Expansion Drive//FAT32 1/0/Download/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27400/discussion-between-tchen-and-user2387962).

Comment: But there are hundreds of them there..

Comment: thanks you've been a great help. I didn't find any .odt files. But at least I know there not in the zip files!! Ju

Comment: Is it possible the dump could change the extenion

Comment: extension of the file type?

Comment: Yea, it is possible, but it all depends on how the dump was made. Other than `.zip` and `.pdf` and `.doc`, what other files are there? By the way, we can [talk more in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27400/discussion-between-tchen-and-user2387962).